# How to add the degrees celcius symbol in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to include the degrees Celsius symbol (°C) in my code, this is what I have and it is not working:

```js
$('#temp').unbind().append((Math.round(temperature - 273.15)) + '&#8451');
```

Comment: try with this `&deg;C`

Comment: Alternatively, you're missing a semicolon after your `&#8451` try `&#8451;` (tested and working)

Comment: Why not just `'°C'`?

Comment: @Bergi Thank You. I did not have that circle symbol so I was looking for the asci code as well. But this saves my day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just miss `;` in `&#8451;`

Answer (score 2):

An HTML entity has the format `&name;` as pointed out already by Arsen.
Here is an alternative found [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref):

```js
var temperature = 305;
$('#temp').unbind().append((Math.round(temperature - 273.15)) + '&deg;');
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div id="temp">Temperature in degrees Celsius is </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply copied the degrees symbol directly from the Character Editor in Windows.

Start --> symbols --> character map

[image]

Then select copy and paste it into your code ...

```
ctx.fillText(degrees.toFixed(2) +"º", x, y + 50);
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is to utilize the in-built `Int.NumberFormat` Javascript object:

```js
const number = 100;

const degrees = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', {
  style: 'unit',
  unit: 'celsius',
});

console.log(degrees.format(number));
```

[You can review the documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat)

Answer (score 0):

use **sup** tag to place O it above a text.

e.g.

```
<p>31<sup>O</sup>C</p>
```

Comment: Degree symbol is a distinct typographical symbol and shall *never* be typed with superscripted letters `o`, `O` or a number `0`.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that this question was asked six years and ten months ago but if anyone stumbles upon this looking for what I was, I found the following to be helpful.

Use the JavaScript method `codePointAt()` to retrieve the code point integer from the symbol:

```
let unicodeDegCel = '℃'.codePointAt(0);
```

This will return the integer **8451**. Now use the JavaScript method `fromCodePoint()` prepended with `String`, using the character code retrieved from `codePointAt()`:

```
let degreesCelcius = String.fromCodePoint(8451);
```

This is was what eventually enabled me to use the degrees celcius symbol in ChartJS.

Source: [Convert a character to its ASCII code in JavaScript](https://www.techiedelight.com/character-to-ascii-code-javascript/)

Answer (score 0):

The hexadecimal code `"\xB0"` generates that Celsius/Fahrenheit sign. :)

```
var degfahren = prompt("suggest a number" , 50);
var degcelc = (degfahren - 32) * 5\9;
console.log(degfahren+"\xB0 deg Fahrenheit "+"is eqaul to the "+degcelc+"\xB0 celcius");
```