# How to get degree symbol in a string?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a constant declared in typescript file as mentioned below.

```
const PASS_SPN_TXT = [ { name: 'PASS V C' },
    { name: 'PASS. T12 C' }];
```

In actual I want the names as PASS V degree symbol C and PASS.T12 degree symbol C.
How to get degree symbol in a string.

Comment: do you want c with a symbol `°`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Or use hexadecimal code \xB0
like this:

```
const PASS_SPN_TXT = [ { name: 'PASS V \xB0C' },
    { name: 'PASS. T12 \xB0C' }];
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. for some reason I ended up with literally:

```
...
'System Temp (\xB0C)'
...
```

What worked for me though (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32543794/2883500) )

```
...
'System Temp (&deg;C)'
...
```